# stop or kill node media server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I am trying to implement stop feature for live video streaming using node-media-server.

Basically I want to stop node-media-server completely, restart it later.

```
const NodeMediaServer = require("node-media-server");
    let config = {
      logType: 3,
      rtmp: {
        port: rtmpPort,
        chunk_size: 60000,
        gop_cache: true,
        ping: 60,
        ping_timeout: 30,
      },
      http: {
        port: httpPort,
        allow_origin: "*",
      },
      relay: {
        ffmpeg: "/usr/bin/ffmpeg",
        tasks: [
          {
            app: "cctv",
            mode: "static",
            edge: "rtsp://" + cameraUrl + "/h264_ulaw.sdp",
            name: "uterum",
            rtsp_transport: "udp",
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    let nms = new NodeMediaServer(config);
    nms.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see on the project github that there is a stop method.

Have you try to use it ?

https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server/blob/master/node_media_server.js

```
 nms.stop();
```

---

**Answer to comment:**

1. Goto the github repo :

   Express file is the app.js
2. Inside it you see

   const NodeMediaServer = require('./');
   ...
   let nms = new NodeMediaServer(config)
   nms.run();

   *You see the NodeMediaServer ?*

   *There is another file in the same folder `node_media_server.js` which exports `module.exports = NodeMediaServer`
   Just a look at this file and you see the stop method.
   That's all.*

Comment: how were you able to pinpoint to this code, so quickly? Will help me if you can write a few lines describing your process to reading code in this case.